# Generic Type applied to method parameter - avoid Type erasure

Tags: java, generics

```
public static abstract class ViewHolder<T> extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }

    public abstract void bindItem(T item);
}
```

Is there a way to ensure `bindItem(T item)` parameter T is exactly T instead of Object?  (As Type erasure replaces the method parameter type T with Object since it is unbounded.)

## Update - accidental Raw Type usage

This is how I ended up implementing the abstract class:

```
static class EventHolder extends ViewHolder {

    @Override
    public void bindItem(Object item) {

    }
}
```

causing the `bindItem` parameter type to be `Object` since the [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) of ViewHolder was subclassed.

---

***Should have been***

```
static class EventHolder extends ViewHolder<Event> {

    @Override
    public void bindItem(Event item) {

    }
}
```

Which forces the correct parameter type.

Sorry.  Late night coding = stupid mistakes.

Comment: What issue are you trying to solve? There will always be type erasure. You'll only get compile time checks.

Comment: Any attempt to call `bindItem` with a non-`T` argument will result in a compiler error. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Didn't you get a warning with your first `EventHolder` because you were extending a raw type?

Comment: Didn't get a warning. Not a Lint warning nor compile warning (just changed my code back and checked again).

Comment: I get a warning when compiling with `javac -Xlint` (1.8.0_131)

Answer (score 0):

You can narrow down the generic type to whatever is needed, for example:

```
public static abstract class ViewHolder<T extends SuperItem>
   ...
}
```

So anywhere inside this class you will get a compile-time warning if there is an object of non-declared type.